# How should I cut odd angle miters when working with molding?

Tags: trim, miter

I am installing some chair rail, and the points where it's a 90 degree connection (inside/outside) are no big deal... I cut 45s and then fit them together. But I have a couple of places where the angle is 130 degrees, so I have to cut at 65.  For this stuff, I was using a hand saw and doing the cut, but I am wondering what the best way to handle these odd angles?  Is there a trick or technique that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to cut mitered corners is with a miter saw, either a hand saw with a miter box or a power miter saw.

I don't know how you're cutting your 45ºs currently. If you're using a hand saw and want good control, I would get a hand miter box with an adjustable angle, [like this one on amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005QVQW). Usually they have stops at common angles like 45º and 22.5º, but you can set it to any angle (I don't have any experience with this model though): [image]

If you want something quick and dirty I would just use a [carpentry protractor / angle finder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004T7P5) to draw a line and then freehand it:

[image]